# Authentication for Vertx Shell

Tags: java, kotlin, ssh, vert.x

I have been trying to make a command line application using vertx shell. But I am facing troubles in connecting to my shell when I am trying to connect to it using ssh authentication. I have followed all the steps that are provided in the documentation, to the best of my knowledge but still can't figure out why I am getting permission denied on trying to connect to the shell.
Below is the snipper I have used to start the shell server:

```
    class ShellVerticle :  CoroutineVerticle() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override suspend fun start() {
        logger.debug("Staring vertx shell")
        val shellOptions = ShellServiceOptions()
            .apply { welcomeMessage = "\nWelcome to Logging Shell Shell\n\n" }
        val shellServer = ShellServer.create(vertx, shellOptions).apply {
            val authProps = JsonObject()
                .put("properties_path", "classpath:shell.properties")
            println(authProps.json)
            val sshTermServer = TermServer.createSSHTermServer(vertx, SSHTermOptions().apply {
                host = "localhost"
                port = 5001
                setKeyPairOptions(JksOptions().setPath("vertx-shell-1.8.jks").setPassword("123456"))
                authOptions = JsonObject().put("provider", "shiro").put("config", authProps)
            })
 
            registerTermServer(sshTermServer)
            listen { res ->
                if (res.failed())
                    res.cause().printStackTrace()
                else
                    logger.info("Logging shell started successfully")
            }
 
        }
        shellServer.registerCommandResolver { listOf(Help::class.java, TraceCommand::class.java).map { Command.create(vertx, it) } }
        logger.info("Commands Registered")
 
    }
}
```

The log on the console after running this:

```
INFO  | 11:31:09 | [main] example.TracerKt (Main.kt:7) - Going to start Shell Verticle
WARN  | 11:31:13 | [vertx-blocked-thread-checker] impl.BlockedThreadChecker (:) - Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 2212 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
{"map":{"properties_path":"classpath:shell.properties"},"empty":false}
INFO  | 11:31:13 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] example.TracerKt (ShellVerticle.kt:73) - Commands Registered
INFO  | 11:31:14 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] example.TracerKt (Main.kt:9) - Going to start Logger Verticle
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] logging.LoggingHandler (Log4J2Logger.java:99) - [id: 0x35e8004c] REGISTERED
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] logging.LoggingHandler (Log4J2Logger.java:99) - [id: 0x35e8004c] BIND: localhost/127.0.0.1:5001
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] logging.LoggingHandler (Log4J2Logger.java:99) - [id: 0x35e8004c, L:/127.0.0.1:5001] ACTIVE
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] logging.LoggingHandler (Log4J2Logger.java:99) - [id: 0x27d1d899] REGISTERED
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] logging.LoggingHandler (Log4J2Logger.java:99) - [id: 0x27d1d899] BIND: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5001
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] logging.LoggingHandler (Log4J2Logger.java:99) - [id: 0x27d1d899, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5001] ACTIVE
INFO  | 11:31:17 | [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] example.TracerKt (ShellVerticle.kt:67) - Logging shell started successfully
```

The properties file:

```
user.billy=test,admin
role.admin=*
```

The output I get when I try to connect to shell:

```
C:\Users\abhrdas>ssh -p 5001 billy@localhost
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
billy@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
billy@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
billy@localhost's password:
billy@localhost: Permission denied (password,keyboard-interactive,publickey).
```

[Picture of my command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brwt3.png)

Please help me with this.
If you can't can you at least please confirm if the code for the Shell Verticle is correct and the commands I have registered will be available if I am somehow able to solve this issue? The commands were already working with the telnet protocol but I haven't been able to run the shell with the ssh protocol.
Also ideally what should I enter for the two different passwords in the console, as I have set only test as the password for the user but the console is asking me for two different passwords.
I am really stuck at this problem, please do help.
Thank you.

Comment: I haven't worked with Vert.x before and do not want to set up a complete project on my own right now. Would you be able to share the project on a code hosting platform like GitHub or a minimal project reproducing the problem? This would make it easier (at least for me) to attempt to help.

Comment: @Endzeit 
https://github.com/abhra04/vertx-cli/tree/master/vertx-cli-example - You can try building this on intellij Idea or any other IDE you wish.
Just to give a bit more idea you can checkout these as well:
1.https://github.com/cinterloper/cintershell
2.https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/shell-examples
You might need to regenerate the jks file as it was generated with JDK 1.8, it might throw errors for other JDK versions.
Thanks a lot for your effort in trying to help.

Comment: @Endzeit Right now I suspect the cause of this issue has something to do with my permissions and all as I am trying to run this code on a cloud based VDI, I might not have enough permissions to access the ssh server. If you are able to at least connect to the server using ssh please let me know, that will also mean a lot.